# avoid $ sign on php for print array value from json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have to Simple code retrieve data from json.i got problem with json properties that contains like department$_identifier. 'department$_identifier' properties contains the value.but php count it as a variable.how to escape this.

Here is my code :

```
foreach ($data as $key => $Attendance) {
        if ($Attendance->department$_identifier == 'Administration') {
           echo $Attendance->department$_identifier;
           echo $Attendance->attendanceDate;
           echo $Attendance->status;
           echo $Attendance->_entityName;
        }
      }
```

How to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use {} like as

```
echo $Attendance->{'department$_identifier'};
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thanks a lot,Its Work..Save my time.

Comment: @RK-Rohan Feel free to accept it as an answer to your question then, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($data as $key => $Attendance) {
    if ($Attendance["department$_identifier"] == 'Administration') {
        echo $Attendance["department$_identifier"];
        echo $Attendance["attendanceDate"];
        echo $Attendance["status"];
        echo $Attendance["_entityName"];
    }
}
```